# Rotation in multidimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a regular pentagon, with coordinates

\begin{align*}
    x(1) &= (2, 0, 1, 1, 0) \\
    x(2) &= (1, 1, 0, 2, 0) \\
    x(3) &= (0, 2, 0, 1, 1) \\
    x(4) &= (0, 1, 1, 0, 2) \\
    x(5) &= (1, 0, 2, 0, 1)
\end{align*}

the side of pentagon is 2. I would like to know if there is way to find hyperplane, so that this pentagon in respect to the hyperplane be 2 dimensional?

**Remark:** the central point can be found by directive ways

$$    \left(\frac{4}{5}+\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{5 \left(\frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{5}\right)}\right)^2-14}\right) (1,1,1,1,1)$$

Comment: Welcome to mathoverlow. You can use LaTeX in formulas but then you have to put dollar signs $ around them. This time I edited the question for you. Next time, please do it yourself.

Comment: The Latex code simplifies the task. thanks for information. I need answer on this question because I the algorithm, which calculates points of figure gives them in high dimensions, but everything can be stored in 3D.

Answer (score 2):

The figure you have described is not a regular pentagon.
A regular pentagon with side $2$ would have diagonal $1 + \sqrt 5$,
but the corresponding "diagonal" of this figure 
(for example, the segment from $x(1)$ to $x(3)$)
has length $\sqrt{10}$.

We can take five vectors parallel to the five sides of the "pentagon"
by taking the differences of coordinates of successive vertices,
$x(k+1) - x(k)$.  If the five vertices all lay in one two-dimensional plane
then these five vectors would all lie in a two-dimensional subspace
parallel to that plane.
But in fact we can take linear combinations of these five vectors
to form a set of four vectors such as the following:

$$
v_1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0}, \quad
v_2 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0}, \quad
v_3 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0}, \quad
v_4 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1}, \quad
$$

These vectors span a four-dimensional subspace, so the five vertices do
not lie in a single plane.

So the five points do not form any object we would normally call a
pentagon, and the object they do form is four-dimensional.

You may want to clarify what you mean by "two-dimensional" in the question.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, but wrong because x(1) and x(3) are not connected. The path is x(1)->x(2)->x(3)->x(4)->x(5)->x(1), all sides are 2.

Comment: @Giorgi Yes, _of course_ $x(1)$ and $x(3)$ are not "connected"; that is why the distance between them should be _greater_ than, not equal to, the distance between adjacent vertices. The problem is, the distance between $x(1)$ and $x(3)$ in your figure is not quite large _enough_. The distance between "not connected" vertices of a regular pentagon is always $\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$ times the distance between "connected" vertices; this is a well-known property of regular pentagons. Can you explain why your "pentagon" does not have this property?

Comment: @Giorgi You should also consider the four-dimensional subspace spanned by the four vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$. That is a separate proof that you do not have a regular pentagon, completely independent of the distances between the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\vx}{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand{\vv}{\mathbf{v}}$Generally, if $\vx_{0}$, ..., $\vx_{k}$ are coplanar points of $\Reals^{n}$ such that $\vx_{0}$, $\vx_{1}$, and $\vx_{2}$ are non-collinear, then the displacement vectors $\vv_{1} = \vx_{1} - \vx_{0}$ and $\vv_{2} = \vx_{2} - \vx_{0}$ are linearly independent, and parallel to the plane containing all the points; that is, each $\vx_{j}$ is *uniquely* of the form
$$
\vx_{0} + s \vv_{1} + t \vv_{2}
\tag{1}
$$
for some scalars $s$, $t$.

The set of points of the form (1) is a parametric description of the plane you seek. (Since the plane lies in $\Reals^{5}$, you would need three equations to describe this plane as the solution set of a linear system.)

Presumably you'll take $\vx_{0}$ to be the center of the pentagon, and $\vx_{1}$, ..., $\vx_{5}$ to be the vertices. In this case, if you perform the Gram-Schmidt algorithm on the ordered basis $(\vv_{1}, \vv_{2})$, obtaining an orthonormal basis $(\Basis_{1}, \Basis_{2})$ with $\vv_{1} = r\Basis_{1}$, then for each $j = 1$, ..., $5$,
$$
\vx_{j} = \vx_{0} + (r\cos \theta_{j}) \Basis_{1} + (r\sin \theta_{j}) \Basis_{2},\qquad \theta_{j} = \tfrac{2(j-1)\pi}{5}.
$$